# Logic programming with multiple fact databases

Tags: prolog, logic-programming, datalog, minikanren

I have to find a logically consistent subset of multiple fact sets (databases). Is there a logic programming language with built-in facilities to do this? If not, are there logic programming languages allowing to operate on multiple fact databases at the same time?

For example, I could use an extra argument for each fact to denote, which database it belongs to, e.g.:

```
class(1, elephant, mammal)
class(2, elephant, mammal)
class(3, elephant, fish)
```

In this case, databases `1` and `2` are consistent. Database `3` is not consistent with the other ones. I'm looking for native language mechanism to avoid implementation "tricks" like this example.\

---

This question can be rephrased as a consistency between different rule sets. The example above would look like this:

```
is(x, mammal) :- is(x, elephant)  /* rule set #1 */
is(x, mammal) :- is(x, elephant)  /* rule set #2 */
is(x, fish) :- is(x, elephant)  /* rule set #3 */
```

Comment: Sure. See e.g. https://logtalk.org/2019/11/13/many-worlds-design-pattern.html